# BTCPay Server with lightening over testnet - Payment issue

Tags: lightning-network, testnet, btcpay

I have recently deployed btcpayserver over **testnet** to demonstrate the user experience to my colleagues.

Lightening Implementation: **LND**

Following are setting
[image: Node Type: Internal]

Every thing seems ok I can see the service status also comes as online moreover this node is now visible in https://1ml.com/testnet

I tried `nc -v server:port` as well that also working. So connection is not an issue apparently.

However while testing payments I tried two wallets and but failed to make a payment.
first I tried [Lightning: Testnet Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=engineering.lightning.LightningApp&hl=en_AU&gl=US) but fails with "invalid invoice or address".
then I tried [Eclair Mobile Testnet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.acinq.eclair.wallet&hl=en_AU&gl=US&showAllReviews=true) it reads the invoice and initiates the transaction but fails after a while. see the result below;

then I tried open channel directly to my node but it scanned it shown a form with pubkey and host details however upon proceeding with full funding it fails with error message "Failed to open channel:incompatible features"

Can someone please help me to understand where I am doing wrong. I am not able to find any further wallets supporting testnet+lightening Also most of the BTCPayServer tutorial videos are using mainnet.

Wallet 1 error
[image]

Wallet 2 error
[image]

Comment: I currently have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Luckily yes but only following wallet worked, please note that its direct APK file for android so be careful https://apkpure.com/simple-bitcoin-wallet-testnet/com.btcontract.wallettest